How to enforce the use of optional chaining for any type object in TypeScript?
I'm trying to enforce the use of optional chaining for accessing properties of any type object in TypeScript to avoid potential runtime errors. For example, I want the following code to throw a TypeScript error:
catch(e: any) {
    const code = e.code; // This should throw a TypeScript error
}

But this code should not throw an error:
catch(e: any) {
    const code = e?.code; // This should not throw a TypeScript error
}

Is there a way to configure TypeScript to enforce this rule or any workaround to achieve this behavior?

For catching errors you can force use of not any to type them: useUnknownInCatchVariables. In general, though: no.

i find unknown annoying because then i have to must cast it to something

any doesn't work this way. Possibly you're looking for the type Record<string, any> | undefined as shown in this playground link but there's no TS rule to do that for you, nor can you choose e to be something other than any or unknown, so you'll need to reassign or assert ("cast") to do that with a catch parameter. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

i've been trying to avoid casting but i see there's no other way as of now.

The any type is intentionally loose in TypeScript; there is no way to make accessing its properties an error directly. You might be able to find or make a linter rule that does this for you (say, for typescript-eslint), but that's not part of the language itself.
If you want a type where indexing into it without checking for nullishness is an error, but which, if defined, behaves similarly to any, then you're looking for something like {[k: string]: any} | null | undefined.
Unfortunately you cannot annotate the catch parameter with anything but any or unknown. There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#20024 to allow something like this, but for now it's not part of the language.  That means you will simply need to use a type assertion or a reassignment to use a type other than any or unknown:
catch (_e: any) {
  const e: { [k: string]: any } | null | undefined = _e;
  e.code; // error! 'e' is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
  e?.code;
}

Here we reassign _e of type any to e of type {[k: string]: any} | null | undefined. That assignment is allowed because any is so loose. After this, e will now only let you access properties if you check for nullishness first.
That's the closest we can get to what you're asking for. Do note that it's unconventional to worry about such things in the first place. While it is technically possible to throw undefined or throw null it's quite unlikely in practice. If you're actually throwing null and undefined in your own code, you should change it to something more conventional. If you're dealing with third-party code which throws null and undefined, you should try to convince them to change that, since nobody expects it.
Playground link to code
